# file_put_content with multiple line from a loop in php

Tags: php

i have trouble printing some lines in a file_put_content

my code looks like this :

```php
<?php
$floor = $_POST['floor'];
$xmlpath = $_POST['xml'];
$_SESSION["floor"] = $_POST['floor'];
$rdc="'rdc': { 'a': 'rdc.png', 'b': 'rdc_b.png', 'v': '0' },"; 

for ($x = 1; $x <= $_POST['floor'] ; $x++) {

$etage =  "'r$x' : { 'a': 'r$x.png', 'b': 'r$x"."_b.png', 'v': '$x' },";
        echo $etage;
        
        
    
    
}
file_put_contents("conf.js", "var appConfig = {
    
'helpwindow': {
        'active': false,
        'background': '#ffffff',
        'text': '#333333',
        'title': 'Aide',
        'content': 'Naviguer autour de la résidence en saisissant avec la souris et en la faisant tourner <img src = \"images/hand_icon.png\" style = \"vertical-align:middle;height:18px;\"/><br/>Zoomer / dézoomer en utilisant les boutons <img src = \"images/zooms.png\" style = \"vertical-align:middle;height:18px;\"/><br/>Rechercher un bien en cliquant sur l\'icône <img src = \"images/menu.png\" style = \"vertical-align:middle;height:18px;\"/>'
    },
    'mainmenu': {
        'background': '#ffffff',
        'width': '160px',
        'borderwidth': '2px',
        'bordercolor': '#000000'
    },
    'margins': '30px', // Marges
    'xmlPath': '$xmlpath', // Chemin du fichier XML
    'imagesPath': 'images', // Chemin du dossier des images
    'plansPath': '', // Chemin du dossier des plans (optionnel)
    'photo_link': '', // Lien de l'icône 'Photo'
    'play_link': '', // Lien de l'icône 'Play'
    'types': {
        'active': true,
        'items': {
            /* Exemple : */
            //'t1': 'image_1.png',
        }
    },
    'etages_display': 'block', // inline = 2 par ligne, block = 1 par ligne
    'etages': {
        /* Exemple : */
        //'rdc': {
        //    'a': 'rdc.png',
        //    'b': 'rdc_b.png',
        //    'v': '4'
        //},   
        $rdc
        $etage

        
    },
    'logos_padding': '10px',
    'logos': {
        /* Exemple : */
        //'nomLogo': 'image_3.png',
    },
    'images': {
        'aerial_4': 'aerial4.png',
        'aerial_4_b': 'aerial4_b.png',
        'aerial_5': '',
        'aerial_5_b': '',
        'photo': '',
        'play': '',
        'compass': 'compass.png',
        'zoom_minus': 'zoom_minus.png',
        'zoom_plus': 'zoom_plus.png',
        'zoom_button': 'zoombutton.png',
        'left': 'left.png',
        'right': 'right.png',
        'zoomin': 'zoomin.png',
        'zoomout': 'zoomout.png',
        'fullscreen': 'fullscreen.png',
        'autorotate': 'autorotate.png',
        'menu': 'menu.png',
        'menu_open': 'menu_open.png',
        'vues': 'vues.png',
        'types': 'type_de_bien.png',
        'close': 'close.png',
    },
};");

?>
```

if the user enter 2 in the form floor, it should print in the file something like this :

'r0' : { 'a': 'r0.png', 'b': 'r0_b.png', 'v': '0' },'r1' : { 'a': 'r1.png', 'b': 'r1_b.png', 'v': '1' },'r2' : { 'a': 'r2.png', 'b': 'r2_b.png', 'v': '2' }
but as you can see, i don't know how to do it, the only things $etage print is the last value the for loop put it in.
i have escape trouble when i try to put an echo inside the file_put_contents, and it seems like doing a foreach loop doesn't help me either.

can someone explain me how i'm suppose to print every iteration of my for loop in a file_put_contents?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you want it to start with `0` you shouldn't start your `for` loop with `$x = 1`. Also, you're overwriting `$etage` on every iteration, add to an array or concat to a string instead

Comment: my bad on r0, actually RDC is hardcoded to be the R0, so floor always start with r1

Comment: Ok, but the content of `$rdc` doesn't look like your desired output. Set `$etage` to an empty string before your `for` loop and use `$etage .= ...` to add to it inside the loop. Make sure to remove the final `,` when done

Comment: It work ! 
$etage .= "'r$x' : { 'a': 'r$x.png', 'b': 'r$x"."_b.png', 'v': '$x' },"; 
is exactly what i needed, thank you so much, how is it called ?

Comment: String concatenation. More on [String Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)